# Overload dereference operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the dereference operator, but compiling the following code results in the error `'initializing' : cannot convert from 'X' to 'int'`:

```
struct X {
    void f() {}
    int operator*() const { return 5; }
};

int main()
{
    X* x = new X;
    int t = *x;
    delete x;
    return -898;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should apply dereference operator to a class type. In your code `x` has a pointer type. Write the following:

```
int t = **x;
```

or

```
int t = x->operator*();
```

Answer (score 14):

You're dereferencing a pointer to `X`. Your class is OK (as far as it's implemented).

```
int main()
{
    X x; // no pointer
    int t = *x; // x acts like a pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the original code to work, you need to overload the int-cast operator for your class:

```
operator int() const { return 5; }
```

Comment: `operator int` has a lot of gotchas and is best avoided. The dereference operator has legitimate use as pointer emulation.

Comment: @David: the ones that convert to `bool` have one more than the others, but maybe it's a drop in the bucket ;v)

Comment: @David: The question is about `int operator*`, not `operator int*`